# Removing DAL dependency from Service Layer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

using a C# n tier application we have a project where we are trying to remove the dependency of the DAL from our service layer. We have taken the using statement reference out of the project along with the reference out of the project.json.

Now we have something like the following in our Service Layer...

```
var stockItem= await _unitOfWork.StockRepo.FindOne(p => p.product == product && p.warehouse == warehouse).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This is exactly the sort of thing we are after. The problem is when we hover over var stockItem the tooltip states DAL.entities.Stock so we still have a dependency. 
So does this mean that our service layer still knows about our DAL. Anyone have any idea how to remove this problem.

Comment: You could extract your entities to another project.

Comment: Your service layer uses your data layer, that is fine. So your service layer would know about the entities as part of this reference. This is quite common, unless you move your entities into another project as mentioned.

Comment: The service layer needs to know about the entities, but not about the rest of the data layer.

Comment: If a method in your data layer is returning these entities, then by default it will know about them!

Comment: So is this like a reference by association then as we have no reference in the Service Layer only in the business layer which is where these methods are being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a point where you have to bring the service layer and DAL together. But you can seperate that into different assemblies.

Definition of the ServiceLayer `Foo.Services.Core.dll`

```
namespace Foo.Services.Core.Models
{
    public class Foo
    {
       ...
    }
}

namespace Foo.Services.Core.DataServices
{
    public interface IFooService
    {
        Task<Foo> GetByIdAsync( int id );
    } 
}
```

Next project will be more concrete with a UnitOfWork `Foo.Services.Impl.UnitOfWork.dll`

```
namespace Foo.Services.Impl.UnitOfWork
{
    public class UnitOfWorkFooService : IFooService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
        public UnitOfWorkFooService( IUnitOfWork uow )
        { 
            _uow = uow;
        }

        public Task<Foo> GetByIdAsync( int id );
        {
            return await _uow.FooRepo.FindOne( ... ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe a total different in the future talking to a REST API `Foo.Services.Impl.RestApi.dll`

```
namespace Foo.Services.Impl.RestAPI
{
    public class RestApiFooService : IFooService
    {
        private readonly IRestApi _restapi;
        public RestApiFooService( IRestApi restapi )
        { 
            _restapi = restapi;
        }

        public Task<Foo> GetByIdAsync( int id );
        {
            return await _restapi.FooEndpoint.GetAsync( id );
        }
    }
}
```